# If $n = xm$ and $n \rightarrow \infty$, then $m \rightarrow \infty$?

Tags: limits

Did Stewart prove the result in green, himself or as an exercise, in *Calculus Early Transcendentals* or the normal version *Calculus*?

I dislike duplicates as much as the next guy.  A result like this, from first year calculus, must have gotten asked here. But I can't find similar posts.

I attempted this, but I got nonplussed. $\infty = \lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} n = \lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} xm $. Now what? The limit is for $n$, but my variables are $xm$.

By the way, if I was the one writing the solution, I would've started with the game plan: turning $(1 + x/n)$ into the form $(1 + 1/n)^n$ in order to apply $e = \lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} (1 + 1/n)^n$. And I wouldn't have changed variable to $m$. Just rewrite $(1 + x/n)$ as $(1 + \dfrac{1}{\frac nx}).$ But if you craved change of variable, I would let $\dfrac xn$ as $\dfrac 1 m$, which is more intuitive than "let $m = n/x$.

> 56. Show that $\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} (1 + \dfrac xn)^n = e^x$ for any $x > 0$.

> [image]

James Stewart, *Calculus Early Transcendentals*  7th ed 2011. p. 231.

Comment: Since $x$ is positive and isn't function of $n$, yes : $m = n/x $. It's basic operation on limits.

Comment: I think you may not be parsing the (somewhat ambiguous and misleading statement) correctly. What is meant is that "if $m = n/x$ then $m$ (as a function of $n$) tends to $\infty$ as $n$ tends to $\infty$; also $n = mx$, therefore:".

Comment: @RobArthan isn't my question's title the same thing as what you wrote? $m= n/x \iff n = mx$.

Comment: Don't rely on the title of your question to state the question: include a complete statement of the question in the body. In this case, the answer to the question in the title is "yes, provided $x > 0$". I was trying to answer the question in the body of your question which is about the statement you highlighted in green.